# How to create search like maps.google.com

Tags: google-maps, search

If we go to maps.google.com. and search "Nepal", it will search "Nepal"
If we seach "McDonalds", it shows restaurants in the current map boundaries.

If we search on map with Geocoder, but Geocoder will not show results in case of "McDonalds" or "KFC" etc.

If we use place library, the this cant search Cities, states, countries.

How can I implement that search? In my application.

Comment: You want to implement google or you want to make use of google?

Comment: I want to create search box with autosuggest and use show results on my map using API v3

Answer (score 0):

Take the user keywords and pass them to geocoder.If no results are returned from geocoder then pass them to places api.
I think that's what google also does.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Places Library](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html). Places can take both geographic locations, including address, and establishments (landmarks, business, government offices, etc.). It also provides you with an autocomplete API as well. There is also a [Places API web service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) that you can use directly from your server.

Comment: Google place library doesn't allow to search using keywords. It searches places based on 1) Center of map and Radius and 2) Map boundaries.

Also Autocomplete API restricts to only select from the suggested option. It not allows to search what user want to search.

Places API web service don't search on map bounds. It needs radius to search.

I want to search strings like "McDonald" and should appear on map.

Comment: Actually, the Places API now allows for use of the keyword parameter in a search request:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchRequests

Answer (score -1):

And this is the example of Autocomplete

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete